# Почему класс show добавляется, но не работает?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

JS - >>>>>>

```
const modalTrigger = document.querySelectorAll("[data-modal]"),
    modal = document.querySelector(".modal");

  function closeModal() {
    modal.classList.remove("show");
    modal.classList.add("hide");
    document.body.style.overflow = "";
  }

  function openModal() {
    modal.classList.remove("hide");
    modal.classList.add("show");
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    clearInterval(modalTimerId);
  }

  modalTrigger.forEach(function (btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
      openModal();
    });
  });
```

HTML ->>>>>>>>>

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal__dialog">
    <div class="modal__content">
      <form action="#">
        <div data-close class="modal__close">&times;</div>
        <div class="modal__title">
          Мы свяжемся с вами как можно быстрее!
        </div>
        <input
          required
          placeholder="Ваше имя"
          name="name"
          type="text"
          class="modal__input"
        />
        <input
          required
          placeholder="Ваш номер телефона"
          name="phone"
          type="phone"
          class="modal__input"
        />
        <button class="btn btn_dark btn_min">Перезвонить мне</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

У меня просто исчезает боковой скролл, так как оверфлоу применился при клике на кнопку, но сама панель не появляется. Я был вынуженден применить до этого просто style.display="block", но теперь это вылезло боком в коде

Comment: В вопросе по CSS нет собственно CSS-кода. Надо добавить

Comment: Судя по вашим скригшотам, у класса `modal` задан `display:none` и он «побеждает» класс `show` (возможно просто потому что идёт в коде ниже)
https://css-live.ru/css/nikto-ne-znaet-css-specifichnost-ne-kaskad.html

Comment: @AlexeyTen Вы были правы, покапавший в элементах, ответ был перед моим носом. В диспетчере на странице четко указанны стили и номера строк, каскад работает все таки безжалостно)

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы сделать `none` элемент снова блоком ( `display: block` ), надо обращаться через родителя (классом выше).

Например:

```
   <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal__dialog show">
        </div>
    </div>
```

то надо обращаться не `.show`, a `.modal.show`

Comment: Ответ был в стилях, код css с моими show и hide стоит выше чем modal. Что странно немного, потому что классы добавляются после нажатия на кнопку, а странница же загрузилась, надо бы еще раз css глянуть получше

Comment: об этом я знаю, но если вы будете использовать обращение через родителя в стилях, оно всегда должно работать (пока не мере у меня работало)